# NginX reverse proxy for Kibana over Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, docker-compose, kibana

I have a Docker Compose setup with NginX, ElasticSearch and Kibana like the following:

```
web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./system/docker/development/web.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - './system/ssl:/etc/ssl/certs'
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  elasticsearch_1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME:-service}_elasticsearch_1"
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch_1
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch_2,elasticsearch_3
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch_1,elasticsearch_2,elasticsearch_3
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es_volume_1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - mynet

  elasticsearch_2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME:-service}_elasticsearch_2"
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch_2
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch_1,elasticsearch_3
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch_1,elasticsearch_2,elasticsearch_3
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es_volume_2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9201
    networks:
      - mynet

  elasticsearch_3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME:-service}_elasticsearch_3"
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch_3
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch_1,elasticsearch_2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch_1,elasticsearch_2,elasticsearch_3
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es_volume_3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9202
    networks:
      - mynet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.7.0
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME:-service}_kibana"
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch_1:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch_1:9200
    networks:
      - mynet
      
volumes:
  es_volume_1: null
  es_volume_2: null
  es_volume_3: null

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.18.0.0/24
        gateway: 172.18.0.1
```

When I (build and) run this using `docker-compose up` I'm able to access Kibana through URL  `http://localhost:5601/` but when I try to setup a reverse proxy for the same using NginX, I get a **502 Bad Gateway** error. Here's my NginX config file:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl http2;

   ssl_certificate /ssl/localhost.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /ssl/localhost.key;

  ...

  location /app/kibana {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

   location ~ /\. {    
      deny all;  
   }
   
   ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is be able to access Kibana like `http://localhost/app/kibana`. The articles I've gone through (like [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/kibana-nginx-proxy)) seem to be focused more on securing Kibana access through NginX (using Basic Auth) rather than the ability to access on a particular path on port 80.

**Update**

So, I changed `localhost` to `kibana` (as suggested by @mikezter) and now it seems to be able to at least find the Kibana service (so there's no more 502 error).

However, then I encountered a blank page with a few errors in browser debug console. Upon searching, I came across this location directive:

```
location ~ (/app|/translations|/node_modules|/built_assets/|/bundles|/es_admin|/plugins|/api|/ui|/elasticsearch|/spaces/enter) {
         proxy_pass          http://kibana:5601;
         proxy_set_header    Host $host;
         proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header    Authorization "";
         proxy_hide_header   Authorization;
  }
```

Now the page loads and there is some UI, but there's still some issue with the scripting, so the page is not available for user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting all the containers in this config via container network. Look at the environment variables set in the Kibana config:

```
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch_1:9200
```

Here you can see, that the hostname of the other container running ElasticSearch is `elasticsearch_1`. In a similar manner, the hostname of the container running Kibana woud be `kibana`. These hostnames are only availiable inside the container network.

So in your Nginx config, you'll have to proxy_pass to `http://kibana:5601` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for this. I changed `localhost` to `kibana` and now it seems to be able to at least find the Kibana service (so there's no more 502 error). However, I encountered a blank page with a few errors in browser debug console. Upon searching, I came across another `location` directive (which I'm adding as an Edit to my question) after which the page loads with some UI, but there's still some issue with the scripting, so the page is not available for user interaction.

Comment: @UzairIshaq please don't edit other ppl's answers with updates to your question.  If you want to reply, use a comment; if you want to share more info about the problem, update your question.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was actually trying to post an Update to my question but somehow clicked Edit on the answer.

Comment: @UzairIshaq you probably don't need it. i'm not familiar with the specifics, you might have to open dev console and look which resources fail to load. then compare the expected url to the ones you are providing in your nginx config. might be worth a new question

Comment: Alrighty. Opening a new question then  :)  Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this might not be a **total** fix for your problem for the second part of the problem but using the following

ELK_VERSION=7.12.0

Kibana seems to work well on the default route '/'

The below worked for me.

```
        server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            server_name $hostname;

            location / {
                proxy_pass          http://kibana:5601;
                # kindly add your header config that works for you
            }
        }
```

**I think it has to do with the way you're configuring your nginx location regex match.**

The configuration I eventually went with was to enable nginx listen on multiple ports.

so I isolated by port exposed by kibanna which listen on the default route.

E.g. in my nginx.conf

```
         server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            server_name $hostname;

            location / {
                proxy_pass          http://identity-api;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
       }

       server {
            listen 81;
            server_name $hostname;

            location / {
                proxy_pass          http://kibana:5601;
                # kindly add your header config that works for you
            }
        }
```

Lastly I update my nginx port in docker-compose

```
  nginx-reverseproxy:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a site-file for Nginx:

`$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/kibana.example.com`

`$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/kibana.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Put the following into it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name kibana.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://kibana_server;
    }
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream kibana_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:5601;
}
```

In your docker-compose.yml, serve Kibana only locally on the host:

```
services:
...
  kibana:
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5601:5601"
...
```

Execute `docker compose up -d`

Run sanity check for your nginx configuration: `sudo nginx -t`.

Reload nginx: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

Access your kibana server at http://kibana.example.org.

PS: Its implied that kibana.example.org is just a placeholder domain name.